# Laravel collect multidimesion array

Tags: multidimensional-array, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am a little confused.

How i can get value for `nama_kategori` and `nama_wil` ?

it's more detail code http://pastebin.com/HXncDnDT

I have a data array like this:

```
[
    {
    "id_rate_kend": 1,
    "kategori": {
       "kat_id": 1,
       "id_jns_kend": 1,
       "nama_kategori": "Kategori 1",
    "jenis_kendaraan": {
       "id_jns_kend": 1,
       "keterangan": "Non Bus dan Non Truk"
    }
    },
    "wilayah": {
       "id_wil": 1,
       "nama_wil": "Wilayah 1"
    },
    "rate_master": {
       "id_rate_mst": 5,
       "type_rate": "1",
       "keterangan": "",
       "tenor_type": "tahun",
       "is_kombinasi": "N",
       "permil": "Y"
    }
    },
]
```

How do i get value for `nama_kategori`? `wilayah`?

Comment: can you also add your Query/Object ? so we can guide you